# How to get django-simple-history work with Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I need to store full history of changes made to objects. I find [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) very appealing but it does not work with [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If I send data to API using PUT (update the object), the object is updated OK but the history records are not updated. If I change the objects manually via './manage.py shell' everything works fine. It looks like tastypie is bypassing signals or something.

Any ideas how I could get this to work as expected?

Comment: Maybe django-tastypie use its own data model (own tables) for recording the `save`, and that is not linked to django-simple-history data model.

Comment: @minder hi. interesting question! I use tastypie too and i might need to keep history of changes. Did you find a solution?

Comment: You should post some example code of how you integrated the two.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm going to attempt to solve this one analytically.

Looking at django-simple-history it seems the project does indeed create history objects on post_save/post_delete signals and provides access to them using a custom model.Manager subclass.

It looks to me that the resource that TastyPie saves is a ModelResource and not your actual Model instance. This proxy model is aware of the orm and performs all the queries on it.

So what I think happens in `simple_history/models.py` is that `contribute_to_class` method declares `models.signals.class_prepared.connect(self.finalize, sender=cls)` but this signal never fires since TastyPie does not initialize an instance of the model...

This seems so strange and I cannot understand why TastyPie does that, or maybe I'm misunderstanding something? Why don't you try to open an issue in the github repo?

Comment: HistoricalRecords are not created when using TastyPie to talk with database. The access to HistoricalRecords via TastyPie is not the subject of this question.

Comment: o I see, github keeps going down for maintenance... i think the answer lies in contribute_to_class, let me elaborate in answer